# How to modify ActiveRecord_Relation output in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreach, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a Post model combined with [gem Acts_as_Taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).

I would like to display all posts with all their tags, but the tags should be sorted by number of their use (number of posts tagged with certain tag).

To do that I looped through ActiveRecord_Relation and did a sort on Tags column:

```
def index
  temp_posts = Post.all.order('updated_at DESC')
  temp_posts.each_with_index do |temp_post, index|
    temp_posts[index].tags = temp_post.tags.sort_by {|tag| -tag.taggings_count}
  end
  @show = temp_posts.first.tags.sort_by {|tag| -tag.taggings_count} # according to this control output it should work
  @posts = temp_posts
end
```

When looking through the control output @show, the tags are sorted as required, but they are not saved into the temp_posts variable. The output is thus unsorted.

What can I do to 'save' the changes I made in the loop?

Comment: You cannot `save` order in a relation. Relation is a magic collection and you cannot change order by assigning. If you want to have ordered collection of tags for a post, you can either add new association (see example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) or just add simple getter-method in Post model, which returns tags in expected order, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the end only with using an invalid variable for saving the sorted tags.

[Acts as Taggable on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) uses variable `tag_list` to store the tags associated with the Tag model. Instead I have wrongly used variable `tags`.

The full correct version of my code:

```
def index
  temp_posts = Post.all.order('updated_at DESC')
  temp_posts.each_with_index do |temp_post, index|
    // CHANGE: temp_posts[index].tags => temp_posts[index].tag_list
    temp_posts[index].tag_list = temp_post.tags.sort_by {|tag| -tag.taggings_count}
  end
  @posts = temp_posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `Tag#taggings_count`, you can order your associations by it. I don't know if this will conflict with what `ActsAsTaggable` is up to, but this is what it would look like in vanilla Rails. Perhaps `ActsAsTaggable` has some options to accomplish the same thing.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings, -> { order(taggings_count: :desc) }
end
```

For more details, see [Scopes for `has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many).

---

If you don't want the order applied globally, [andrykonchin's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529526/how-to-modify-activerecord-relation-output-in-ruby-on-rails#comment56817622_34529526) is a good one. Write a `Post#sorted_tags` method and you can access it on the `Post` when you want it. Memoizing it into an instance variable will prevent extra database queries.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sorted_tags
    @sorted_tags ||= tags.sort_by(&:taggings_count).reverse
  end
end
```